# Dynamically passing Query String for selecting columns in PySpark Dataframe method selectExpr()

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am generating a query string dynamically as follows and passing it to selectExpr().

```
queryString=''''category_id as cat_id','category_department_id as cat_dpt_id','category_name as cat_name''''
df.selectExpr(queryString)
```

As per document

selectExpr(*expr) :
    Projects a set of SQL expressions and returns a new DataFrame.
    This is a variant of select() that accepts SQL expressions.

**The issue is that the variable "queryString" is being treated as a single string instead of three separate columns ( and rightly so ).** Following is the error:

> : org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
>   .........
>
> == SQL ==
>
> 'category_id as cat_id', 'category_department_id as cat_dpt_id', 'category_name as cat_name'
>
> ------------------------^^^

**Is there any way I can pass the dynamically generated "queryString" as an argument of selectExpr().**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If possible, while generating your query string, try to put the individual column expressions in a list right away instead of concatenating them into one string.

If not possible, you can split your query string to have seperated column expressions which can be passed to `selectExpr`.

```
# generate some dummy data
data= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(5, 3)), columns=list("abc"))
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

df.show()

+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  4|
|  1|  2|  1|
|  3|  3|  2|
|  3|  2|  2|
|  2|  0|  2|
+---+---+---+

# create example query string
query_string="'a as aa','b as bb','c as cc'"

# split and pass
column_expr = query_string.replace("'", "").split(",")

df.selectExpr(column_expr).show()

+---+---+---+
| aa| bb| cc|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  4|
|  1|  2|  1|
|  3|  3|  2|
|  3|  2|  2|
|  2|  0|  2|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: great solution!